# Arrays declared globally gives out of scope error in functions

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array

I have these arrays declared globally

```
char str1[] = "6541254939322816220209974565477289648317";
char str2[] = "3142522751761601737419090933147067701840";

int str1_size = strlen(str1);
int str2_size = strlen(str2);

int lcs[str1_size][str2_size];
int arrows[str1_size][str2_size];
```

But when I access this inside a function, it gives

```
lcs was not declared in this scope
```

also

```
array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
int lcs[str1_size][str2_size];
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The "array bound is not an integer constant" is the real error.  The "lcs was not declared in this scope" is a side-effect.

Comment: Can you please point out how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

```
int a[dim];
```

where `dim` isn't a compile-time know constant (`constexpr` by example) isn't C++ standard; maybe it's possible with some extension with some compiler but isn't C++ standard.

So, in your case

```
int lcs[str1_size][str2_size];
int arrows[str1_size][str2_size];
```

where `str1_size` and `str2_size` are normal (not `constexpr`, not `const` initialized with literals) variables, is an error.

If you could redefine `str1_size` and `str2_size` as follows

```
constexpt int str1_size = strlen(str1);
constexpr int str2_size = strlen(str2);
```

the `lcs` and `arrows` definition could works.

Unfortunately (1) `str1` and `str2` aren't `constexpr` and (2) `std::strlen()` isn't `constexpr`.

But if declare `str1`/`str2` `constexpr` and write a `constexpr` alternative to `std::strlen`...

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::size_t lenStr (char const * str)
 {
   std::size_t  ret{};

   while ( *(str++) )
      ++ret;

   return ret;
 }

constexpr char str1[] = "6541254939322816220209974565477289648317";
constexpr char str2[] = "3142522751761601737419090933147067701840";

constexpr auto str1_size = lenStr(str1);
constexpr auto str2_size = lenStr(str2);

int lcs[str1_size][str2_size];
int arrows[str1_size][str2_size];

int main ()
 {
 }
```

Unfortunately the preceding code require C++14 (in C++11 it's impossible write so complex `constexpr` functions).

In C++11 you should write `lenStr()` in a recursive way

```
constexpr std::size_t lenStr (char const * str, std::size_t ret = 0u)
 { return *str ? lenStr(++str, ++ret) : ret; }
```